# OpenCSV read specific column

Tags: android, csv, opencsv

i am facing small problem while using OPENCSV and trying to read specific column from a line. I have a csv file that looks like this

```
"ID","Name","Name2","Date","Author"
"1","Alex","Example","18.3.2016","Alex"
```

Now i want to read only the column 2 and 3 (Name and Name2).

My code looks like this

```
try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filelocation));

            String [] nextLine;
            int rowNumber = 0;

            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                rowNumber++;
                for(int i = 0; i< nextLine.length ; i++){
                    System.out.println("Cell index: " + i);
                    System.out.println("Cell Value: " + nextLine[i]);
                    System.out.println("---");
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I already tried setting the "i" variable manually to 1 and 2. But then i am getting 4 same results shown in log. What is missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never mind, i found the trick.

Here is how it should look.

```
try {

            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filelocation));

            String [] nextLine;
            int rowNumber = 0;
            while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                rowNumber++;
                String name = nextLine[1];
                String name2 = nextLine[2];
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

After it, i could get the string value and work with it.